# Exclude / Blacklist Permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I'm building a website and I was wondering if it is possible to exclude certain permalinks from beings used.

For example: if my website has a demo of a project running on `www.example.com/demo/` and a user creates a page called demo, I don't want WordPress to create a permalink like `www.example.com/demo/`.

Is there a way to exclude these permalinks? So that WordPress will take the next available permalink? Like `www.example.com/demo-2/` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.  I found this post and tested, it worked for me:

http://wpdreamer.com/2012/03/how-to-define-reserve-slugs-for-wordpress-posts-and-pages/

If you don't want to edit your functions.php file an inelegant solution you can try is to create empty placeholder pages with the permalinks you'd like to reserve.  If there is a physical directory on the server with that same name that would take precedence over the rewritten WordPress URL.  So for example, if you create a WordPress page with slug "demo" and a physical directory in your web public dir called, "demo" you could use that for your demo site files.

Personally I like to use subdomains for this purpose myself to keep any demo work segregated from production, but that's just an opinion.

Comment: I prefer subdomains too, but it's for an existing website with some old projects that need to stay there for multiple reasons. But if it's possible with Wordpress, I'll give it a try. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Comment: **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** See [How to reference material written by others](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and [How do I write a good answer?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/).